# Fragment onStart called but not onResume resulting in blank screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a highly intermittent problem I haven't been able to solve, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it further.

I have a fragment that gets loaded via replace when a transaction is complete. Most of the time, everything works perfectly fine.  Intermittently though, the fragment doesn't finish loading, and it only shows a blank screen.  I'd say it's less than 1% of the time this happens, but it's a really bad spot to happen.

I've put tags before/after the life cycle events, and it's going into onStart() but it never calls onResume [I put tags before/after the super.onResume()] when this happens, neither get logged.  When it works, it logs the onResume call correctly.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    Log.i(CLASS_NAME, "Entering on onStart");
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(CLASS_NAME, "Exiting on onStart");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.i(CLASS_NAME, "Entering on onResume");
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(CLASS_NAME, "Exiting on onResume");
}
```

There's nothing in the logs when this happens to indicate that anything has gone wrong, but, if I try to leave the screen, it will throw an exception that it can't save it's state.

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active TransactionCompleteFragment{2b12a67c} has cleared index: -1"

As far as I can tell, it's trying to save the state, but the fragment isn't there properly so it blows up.  But this is the result of the fragment not loading in the first place.

What could cause the onResume to not be called?  Also, it's not throwing a super.onResume not called exception, so it's clearly okay with it not being called and simply showing a blank screen?

The best I can do is check the logs once it's happened and hope that some additional logging gives some insight, but I'm out of ideas on what to log or where to look?

Comment: Is it possible that you are consuming a possible runtime exception, that is being thrown somewhere in the onStart() method, without logging it?
Any king of generic try - catch (Exception e) blocks or unhandled exception handlers may be hiding the real cause from you, so I would look there first.

Comment: There's nothing actually being called in the onStart() other than logging to see if it happened.  I only have one try/catch in the fragment and it's in the onAttach() and it does log it.   Is it possible an uncaught exception in the host activity could be interfering with the fragment?  I can take a closer look in there.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I think it is highly possible. Fragment lifecycle methods can be called as a result of activity lifecycle methods, so an exception there can possibly cause this strange behavior. I hope you can hunt the problem down.

Comment: There isn't anything that's caught and not logged that would cause a problem.  I did fine one, but it's okay and completely unrelated.